# SQL transform table with sum based on values

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database

i have table like this:

| operation_id | order_id | qty | qty_type | detail_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 240 | ready | glued |
| 1 | 1 | 199 | ready | unglued |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | done | glued |
| 1 | 2 | 50 | ready | glued |

and would like to transform into this. it means to add 4 columns and to sum them from above table based on a conditions, like `detail_type = 'glued'`, `qty_type = 'ready'` etc.

| operation_id | order_id | qty_glued_ready | qty_unglued_ready | qty_glued_done | qty_unglued_done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 240 | 199 | 10 | 10 |

can somebody help me how query should look like?

Comment: If you want it in rows, something like `SELECT SUM(qty), qty_type, detail_type FROM table GROUP BY 2,3`, but that's not a complete solution

Comment: Please add a tag for the DB system you are using to your question! Some of the advanced SQL features are specific to it.

Comment: How is your `qty_glued_done` just 10?
Please explain

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is just an example that you have mentioned in your OP and it is not accurate according to your table data you have mentioned.
I don't understand how your `qty_glued_done` is 10

But here is something you can start working out with:

```
SELECT o.`operation_id`, o.`order_id`,
SUM(CASE WHEN `detail_type`='glued' AND o.`qty_type`='ready' THEN o.`qty` ELSE 0 END) AS qty_glued_ready,
SUM(CASE WHEN `detail_type`='unglued' AND o.`qty_type`='ready' THEN o.`qty` ELSE 0 END) AS qty_unglued_ready
(and so on)
 FROM `operation_table` o GROUP BY o.`operation_id`
```